# How to Apply Dropdownlist Control Script to an .aspx Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, master-pages

I'm currently starting to delve into the world of ASP.Net. Thus far, I've been creating most of my pages in HTML styling with CSS accordingly and more recently I've been applying a Site.Master page to my pages to neaten up the code. I'm creating a page that needs a drop down list control that will eventually reach into a database and display pertinent information, but for now I've kept it simple, and the page simply updates with "You have selected Item 1" when you select an item on the drop down list. Problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to apply the scripting to the page.

So far this is what I have:

```
<%@ Page Title="Bowtie Performance Parts - Inventory" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="parts.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default"%>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<!--Dropdown Menu Setup-->
<head>

</head>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h1 class="defaultTitle">Parts Catalog</h1>
    <p id="defaultLarge">Please Choose from the list below to get started!</p>

    <center>
        <form id="PartsForm" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList id="dropDown2" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Please Choose</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem disabled="disabled">--Motors--</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4 Cylinder</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>6 Cylinder</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>8 Cylinder</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem disabled="disabled">--Intakes--</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem disabled="disabled">--Forced Induction--</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Superchargers</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Turbos</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList></form>
   </center>
</asp:Content>
```

The page is styled and displays as expected, the drop down menu displays and works as it should, but now I'm trying to find out where to place the script so that when I choose an item on the list, it displays "You have selected Item #".

```
<script  runat="server">
Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   mess.Text="You selected " & dropDown2.SelectedItem.Text
End Sub
</script>
```

Placing this script anywhere in the code results in an error and the page not compiling correctly. I'm new at using C# and ASP.net, and I'm not sure I have a grasp on the logic of how to do this. I've looked at plenty of examples as such:

```
<script  runat="server">
Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   mess.Text="You selected " & drop1.SelectedItem.Text
End Sub
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList id="drop1" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button Text="Submit" OnClick="submit" runat="server"/>
<p><asp:label id="mess" runat="server"/></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But applying the script that way prevents me from referencing the Site.Master page which contains a Banner, NavBar and a link to a .css file that style the entire site (going for uniformity across all webpages).

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance,
Tyler Dean

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind use drop1_SelectedIndexChanged event

```
Protected Sub drop1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles drop1.SelectedIndexChanged

  mess.text = drop1.SelectedValue     

End Sub
```

This is in VB but you can convert it to C#.